# How to count up X times after an element is found in a 2d Array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration

I am fairly new to java, and I am just wondering how I would find an element, X amount of spaces, from the desired element in a 2D array. Here's an example to explain if what i'm asking doesn't make sense :

```
String[][] array = {{"1", "5", "7"},
                    {"8", "12" "15"},
                    {"2", "21", "16"}
                    };
```

Let's say the desired String is "5", I know how to find that. Now let's say if the user wanted to count upwards 3 times (starting count from 0). How would I get it to return the value of 15?

Comment: What if we converted the 2D array to 1D array, then we can find any element inside it easily.

Comment: what does upward mean and how do you expect 15 to be the output? Also show us something that you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to find an algorithm that can step through an arbitrary amount of slots in the array. With 2D arrays (assuming steps through the array can loop back to the beginning of the array if you reach the end of it), a problem like this screams "modulo."

Run through a couple examples and you can start to construct an algorithm. For the column of the array, the algorithm is as simple as

`(currentColumn + numberOfSteps) % sizeOfRow`

Using this algorithm with your example, starting from index [0][1], and plugging in corresponding values into the equation above, you get the following:

`columnIndex = (1+4)%3 = 2`

Now you need to come up with an algorithm to find the corresponding row value. An algorithm corresponding to the row value would be:

`(currentRow + ((currentColumn + numberOfSteps) / sizeOfRow)) % numberOfRows`

Note that this algorithm used with integer algebra in Java floors the resulting integer from the division. This is key is determining whether or not the steps will flow into the next row, or stay in the same one (if you're at column 0 and take 2 steps, you need to stay in the same row: (0+2)/3 = 0) Plugging in the values from your example, you get the following:

`rowIndex = 0 + ((1+4)/3)%3 = 0 + 1 = 1`

Note that these algorithms assume that you will loop back through to the beginning of array if you go past the last slot in the array. In general when faced with problem like this, think "modulo," and go through some examples to find an algorithm that works.

Using these algorithms to find the new index values: [1][2],you can retrieve the corresponding value from the 2D array. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though there are a couple of errors in your example:

- I think that there should be a comma after "12"
- By going up 3 times (starting count from 0) I think you mean going up 4 times, counting 0, 1, 2, 3.  It's still going up 4 times.

Assuming that I'm correct about both of those, the answer depends on whether the 2d array is rectangular (all sub-arrays the same length, as in your example) or ragged (for instance, { {1}, {2, 4, 6} }.  I'll assume rectangular, since that's what's in your example (and besides, it's simpler).

The fundamental part of your posed problem is: Given the indexes 'm, n' of an element of the array of arrays, find m2 and n2, which are the indexes of the element that's X positions above it.  In your example, m=0 and n=1, X = 4, and you want to calculate m2 which should be 1, and n2 which should be 2.  We will also need the length of the inner arrays; we can call that 'len', and it is equal to array[0].length.

The best way that I see of doing it is in three steps:

1. compute a single-variable index for m,n, treating the array as a strung-out 1-dimensional array.  Let's call this index 'i'; in your example, i would start at 1 ("1" is at position 0, "5" is at position 1, "7" is at position 2, "8" is at position 3, "12" is at position 4, and "15" is at position 5).  In general, you would do this the statement 'i = m*len + n;'.
2. Add X to i to find the new single-variable index.  In your example, we would add X=4 to i=1 and you get i=5, which is where the desired "15" is.
3. Convert the new value of 'i' into m2 and n2.  We would do that using / and %: m2 = i/len and n2 = i%len.  In your example, m2 = 5/3 = 1, and n2 = 5%3 = 2, as desired.

So, the whole sequence is:

```
i = m*len + n;
i += x; // I switched to lower case to conform to Java standards
m2 = i/len;
n2 = i%len;
```

I hope that makes sense.  Let us know if you need to deal with ragged arrays.  That solution will be rather slower and more complicated.